# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't find a solution for this but here is a screenshot of the error.

[image]

This is what the error looks like when I go to the page localhost:3000

Comment: I think you should look at reading some books on rails or tutorials like: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: @neils, Isn't that apparent that the error is not related to the code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Stop your server at the command line, and run this:

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Looks like you've written a migration, but haven't migrated your database yet.

Comment: Thanks just another question, now that it works when I go to /user I get another error "No route matches [GET] "/user"", D you nkow how to fix this ?

Comment: You need to put resources :users in your routes.rb file. The tutorial that @rainkinz mentioned above will help you get started.

Comment: Actually we do not need  to stop the server execution, only need to open a new tab and run the above code

Answer (score 1):

Run console:

> bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: Not steps. Options, maybe. Two possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you might be in wrong directory ? i was running rails server from wrong folder when i got this error.

Comment: rails server just launches the server. This error is not because of being in the wrong directory, but because he created a migration on the database and has not run the migration

Answer (score 0):

prepare the migration for test using this command.

```
rake test:prepare
```

It should work now.